# How do I throw an Exception from inside a Parallel.ForEach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach, exception, parallel-processing

I have a `Parallel.Foreach` loop which downloads files like so:

```
try
{
     var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
     parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8;
     int failedFiles = 0;
     Parallel.ForEach(FilesToDownload, parallelOptions, tile =>
     {
         bool downloaded = DownloadTile(File);
         if (downloaded)
         {
              //Downloaded :)
         }
         else
         {
               failedFiles++;
               if (failedFiles > 10)
               {
                   throw new Exception("10 Files Failed to download. Failing download");
               }
          } 
          parallelOptions.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw; //This throws it up to a main method that cancels my program
}
```

and I was wondering what is the correct way for throwing an `Exception` from inside the `Parallel.Foreach` method? In my instance I think I am going to see the exception thrown 8 times as soon as the first exception is thrown.

What is the correct way to throw exceptions in `Parallel.ForEach` loops?

Comment: It's not safe to increment `failedFiles` from multiple threads like that.

Comment: There is an article about this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I'm not too worried about the `ThreadSafety` of the method as it won't have too much of an impact. @Kevin Crowell your example shows how to handle exceptions but it talks about waiting for the thread to complete. I want to throw the exception as soon as 10 Files failed. .e.g If I have 1000 files and the first 10 fail I don't want to process the other 990

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, better to use `Interlocked.Increment(ref failedFiles)` instead of `failedFiles++`. Otherwise it can happen that you have 10-15 failures, but you end up with a counter with a value something like 7-8, because of the lack of cache synchronization and the effect of compiler/jitter optimizations.
The loop of your program might throw more exceptions, but at the end it will be aggregated into a single `AggregateException`, and the outter `catch()` will receive that single exception instance. If you do not want more exceptions in the `AggregateException`, you can use `==` instead of `>`

```
if (Interlocked.Increment(ref failedFiles) == 10)
```

When an exception is thrown inside the loop, `Parallel.ForEach` prevents other iterations to start, then it waits for the currently running iterations to finish, then it aggregates all the exceptions it caught, packs it into an `AggregateException` and throws that single instance. It means that in your case a single exception will prevent further downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CancellationToken.Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321635%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Also have a look at [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256691(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can also stop your `Parallel.Foreach` and throw an exception.

This [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721(v=vs.110).aspx) demonstrates how to stop a `For` loop; however, you can stop a `ForEach` loop in the same way. See the snippet below.

```
private static void StopLoop()
{
    double[] source = MakeDemoSource(1000, 1);
    ConcurrentStack<double> results = new ConcurrentStack<double>();

    // i is the iteration variable. loopState is a  
    // compiler-generated ParallelLoopState
    Parallel.For(0, source.Length, (i, loopState) =>
    {
        // Take the first 100 values that are retrieved 
        // from anywhere in the source. 
        if (i < 100)
        {
            // Accessing shared object on each iteration 
            // is not efficient. See remarks. 
            double d = Compute(source[i]);
            results.Push(d);
        }
        else
        {
            loopState.Stop();
            return;
        }

    });

    Console.WriteLine("Results contains {0} elements", results.Count());
}
```

If you want, you can use `ConcurrentStack` the same way to gather exceptions to return as soon as the loop is stopped.

Comment: can you place the most important things in your answer? If the links go offline than is your answer is unuseable.